# Getting XFC0004 Missing default constructor for "System.String"

Tags: maui

Running the following sample code from Microsoft Maui web page:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=netstandard" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Single_Primative_string_argument.MainPage">
   <CollectionView>
      <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
         <scg:List x:TypeArguments="sys:String">
            <sys:String>Baboon</sys:String>
            `your text`
            <sys:String>Capuchin Monkey</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Blue Monkey</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Squirrel Monkey</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Howler Monkey</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Japanese Macaque</sys:String>
         </scg:List>
      </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
   </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

Getting

> Error "XFC0004   Missing default constructor for "System.String"

Cant figure it out, Any assistance is appreciated...

Screen Image Attached...

Tried everything I could think of... Name spaces are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XAML** can create any public object, including ones with parameterized
constructors – you just need to tell it where the type lives, you should supply the namespace:  `xmlns:sys` and `xmlns:scg` like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
 
             x:Class="MauiAppTest01.MainPage">


    <CollectionView>

        <CollectionView.ItemsSource>

            <scg:List x:TypeArguments="sys:String">

                <sys:String>Baboon</sys:String>

                <sys:String>Capuchin Monkey</sys:String>

                <sys:String>Blue Monkey</sys:String>

                <sys:String>Squirrel Monkey</sys:String>

                <sys:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</sys:String>

                <sys:String>Howler Monkey</sys:String>

                <sys:String>Japanese Macaque</sys:String>

            </scg:List>

        </CollectionView.ItemsSource>

    </CollectionView>
```

Comment: Bingo, You hit the nail on the head. I changed my code to reflect your recommended namespaces and it resolved my problem. I had xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"
xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=netstandard"

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```xml
<x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
   <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
   <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
   <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
   <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
   <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
   <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
   <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
</x:Array>
```